# Prove « If P(A) is a subset of P(B) => A is a subset of B »

Tags: logic, formal-languages

I need to prove «If P(A) is a subset of P(B) => A  is a subset of  B», generally, I understand the main way I should prove it, but the problem is in the formal, pedantic language I have to use to prove such statement.

General proof is:
1. Let suppose «**a**» is any element of **A**
2. If «**a**» is in **A**, thus «**a**» is a subset of **P(A)**…

The problem is in the formal and pedantic way to right it, can I just write, that element «**a**» is a subset of **P(A)** or should I define additional set, which will be a subset of **P(A)** and element «**a**» will be a part of this new set.

Please, help me to write such prove in a formal way with the correct syntax.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to search the site? It's been asked at least twice before.

Comment: $A\in\mathcal{P}(A)$, so $A\in\mathcal{P}(B)$ by hypothesis; therefore $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: @egreg: +1, elegant.

Comment: I'm a newbie on this site and it's quite difficult to search because of all these math special symbols…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to distinguzuish better between elements and sets, that is between $\in $and $\subseteq$.
So assume $P(A)\subseteq P(B)$. Let $a\in A$. Then $\{a\}\subseteq A$, hence $\{a\}\in P(A)$, hence $\{a\}\in P(B)$, hence $\{a\}\subseteq B$, hence $a\in B$.

Comment: Why going down to elements?

Answer (score 7):

1. $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is the set of subsets of $A$. In particular $A\in\mathcal{P}(A)$.
2. Since, by hypothesis, $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq\mathcal{P}(B)$, we infer that $A\in\mathcal{P}(B)$.
3. From $A\in\mathcal{P}(B)$ we get, by definition, $A\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 4):

The element $a$ is neither an element nor a subset of $\wp(A)$, but the set $\{a\}$ is an element of $\wp(A)$, and that’s what you need to use:

> Let $a\in A$. Then $\{a\}\subseteq A$, so $\{a\}\in\wp(A)$. And $\wp(A)\subseteq\wp(B)$, so $\{a\}\in\wp(B)$, and therefore ...?